# How can I solve this problem - Instance of 'CategoryModel'? Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to fetch data from api with Dio , But I found an error in my debug console - **Instance of 'CategoryModel'** . I don't know why I face this error.

My Problem Issue ScreenShot

[image: Here Is My Problem Issue ScreenShot]

The Json File

```json
{
    "categories": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Fruits & Vegetables",
        "slug": "fruits--vegetables",
        "image": "public\/uploads\/category\/1642326298-fruits-and-vegetables.png",
        "frontProduct": "1",
        "level": null,
        "status": "1",
        "created_at": "2022-01-01T18:15:36.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-15T22:44:58.000000Z",
        "subcategories": [{
            "id": 1,
            "subcategoryName": "Formula and Energy Boosters",
            "slug": "formula-and-energy-boosters",
            "image": "public\/uploads\/subcategory\/1642051209-formula-n-energy-boosters.jpg",
            "banner": "public\/uploads\/subcategory\/1642060781-banner.jpg",
            "category_id": "1",
            "status": "1",
            "created_at": "2022-01-01T19:00:19.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-12T20:59:41.000000Z",
            "childcategories": [{
                "id": 1,
                "childcategoryName": "Stylish T-shirts",
                "slug": "stylish-t-shirts",
                "image": null,
                "banner": null,
                "subcategory_id": "1",
                "status": "1",
                "created_at": "2022-01-01T19:02:45.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-01-01T19:02:45.000000Z"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "subcategoryName": "Baby Milk and Foods",
            "slug": "baby-milk-and-foods",
            "image": "public\/uploads\/subcategory\/1642053444-baby-milk-and-food.jpg",
            "banner": null,
            "category_id": "1",
            "status": "1",
            "created_at": "2022-01-01T19:07:13.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-12T18:57:24.000000Z",
            "childcategories": [{
                "id": 2,
                "childcategoryName": "Shirt Collection",
                "slug": "shirt-collection",
                "image": null,
                "banner": null,
                "subcategory_id": "2",
                "status": "1",
                "created_at": "2022-01-01T19:08:35.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-01-01T19:08:35.000000Z"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "subcategoryName": "Diapers",
            "slug": "diapers",
            "image": "public\/uploads\/subcategory\/1642053483-diaper.jpg",
            "banner": null,
            "category_id": "1",
            "status": "1",
            "created_at": "2022-01-01T19:25:37.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-12T18:58:03.000000Z",
            "childcategories": [{
                "id": 5,
                "childcategoryName": "Jeans Pant",
                "slug": "jeans-pant",
                "image": null,
                "banner": null,
                "subcategory_id": "3",
                "status": "1",
                "created_at": "2022-01-01T19:39:23.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-01-01T19:39:23.000000Z"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Meat & Fish",
        "slug": "meat--fish",
        "image": "public\/uploads\/category\/1642326372-meat-and-fish.webp",
        "frontProduct": "1",
        "level": null,
        "status": "1",
        "created_at": "2022-01-01T18:17:51.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-15T22:46:12.000000Z",
        "subcategories": [{
            "id": 4,
            "subcategoryName": "Saree",
            "slug": "saree",
            "image": "public\/uploads\/subcategory\/1641816956-subcategory-6.jpg",
            "banner": null,
            "category_id": "2",
            "status": "1",
            "created_at": "2022-01-01T19:27:23.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-10T01:15:56.000000Z",
            "childcategories": [{
                "id": 6,
                "childcategoryName": "Cotton Saree",
                "slug": "cotton-saree",
                "image": null,
                "banner": null,
                "subcategory_id": "4",
                "status": "1",
                "created_at": "2022-01-01T19:40:00.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-01-01T19:40:00.000000Z"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 5,
            "subcategoryName": "Salwar Kamiz",
            "slug": "salwar-kamiz",
            "image": "public\/uploads\/subcategory\/1641816945-subcategory-7.jpg",
            "banner": null,
            "category_id": "2",
            "status": "1",
            "created_at": "2022-01-01T19:28:02.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-10T01:15:45.000000Z",
            "childcategories": [{
                "id": 3,
                "childcategoryName": "Original Indian Dress",
                "slug": "original-indian-dress",
                "image": null,
                "banner": null,
                "subcategory_id": "5",
                "status": "1",
                "created_at": "2022-01-01T19:29:25.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-01-01T19:29:25.000000Z"
            }, {
                "id": 4,
                "childcategoryName": "Block Batik Dress",
                "slug": "block-batik-dress",
                "image": null,
                "banner": null,
                "subcategory_id": "5",
                "status": "1",
                "created_at": "2022-01-01T19:30:12.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-01-01T19:30:12.000000Z"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 6,
            "subcategoryName": "Western",
            "slug": "western",
            "image": "public\/uploads\/subcategory\/1641816838-subcategory-3.jpg",
            "banner": null,
            "category_id": "2",
            "status": "1",
            "created_at": "2022-01-01T19:28:31.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-10T01:13:58.000000Z",
            "childcategories": [{
                "id": 7,
                "childcategoryName": "Tops",
                "slug": "tops",
                "image": null,
                "banner": null,
                "subcategory_id": "6",
                "status": "1",
                "created_at": "2022-01-01T19:40:30.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-01-01T19:40:30.000000Z"
            }, {
                "id": 8,
                "childcategoryName": "Leggings",
                "slug": "leggings",
                "image": null,
                "banner": null,
                "subcategory_id": "6",
                "status": "1",
                "created_at": "2022-01-01T19:40:46.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-01-01T19:40:46.000000Z"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Milk & Dairy",
        "slug": "milk--dairy",
        "image": "public\/uploads\/category\/1642326427-milk-and-dairy.png",
        "frontProduct": null,
        "level": null,
        "status": "1",
        "created_at": "2022-01-15T22:47:07.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-15T22:47:07.000000Z",
        "subcategories": [{
            "id": 7,
            "subcategoryName": "Dress",
            "slug": "dress",
            "image": "public\/uploads\/subcategory\/1641816822-subcategory-2.jpg",
            "banner": null,
            "category_id": "3",
            "status": "1",
            "created_at": "2022-01-01T19:55:10.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-10T01:13:42.000000Z",
            "childcategories": [{
                "id": 11,
                "childcategoryName": "Shirt",
                "slug": "shirt",
                "image": null,
                "banner": null,
                "subcategory_id": "7",
                "status": "1",
                "created_at": "2022-01-01T19:58:39.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-01-01T19:58:39.000000Z"
            }, {
                "id": 12,
                "childcategoryName": "Pant",
                "slug": "pant",
                "image": "public\/uploads\/childcategory\/1642335874-pant-logo.jpg",
                "banner": "public\/uploads\/childcategory\/1642335874-pants-banner.png",
                "subcategory_id": "7",
                "status": "1",
                "created_at": "2022-01-01T19:59:05.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-01-16T01:24:34.000000Z"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 8,
            "subcategoryName": "Footwear",
            "slug": "footwear",
            "image": "public\/uploads\/subcategory\/1641816595-subcategory.jpg",
            "banner": "public\/uploads\/subcategory\/1641821574-kids-banner.png",
            "category_id": "3",
            "status": "1",
            "created_at": "2022-01-01T19:55:36.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-10T02:32:54.000000Z",
            "childcategories": [{
                "id": 9,
                "childcategoryName": "Shoe",
                "slug": "shoe",
                "image": null,
                "banner": null,
                "subcategory_id": "8",
                "status": "1",
                "created_at": "2022-01-01T19:57:23.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-01-01T19:57:23.000000Z"
            }, {
                "id": 10,
                "childcategoryName": "Leather Sandal",
                "slug": "leather-sandal",
                "image": null,
                "banner": null,
                "subcategory_id": "8",
                "status": "1",
                "created_at": "2022-01-01T19:58:02.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-01-01T19:58:02.000000Z"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Food",
        "slug": "food",
        "image": "public\/uploads\/category\/1642326638-food.jpg",
        "frontProduct": "1",
        "level": null,
        "status": "1",
        "created_at": "2022-01-01T18:24:59.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-15T22:50:38.000000Z",
        "subcategories": []
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Baby Care",
        "slug": "baby-care",
        "image": "public\/uploads\/category\/1642326689-baby-care.png",
        "frontProduct": "1",
        "level": null,
        "status": "1",
        "created_at": "2022-01-01T18:27:28.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-15T22:51:29.000000Z",
        "subcategories": []
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Health & Beauty",
        "slug": "health--beauty",
        "image": "public\/uploads\/category\/1642326774-health-and-beauty.png",
        "frontProduct": "1",
        "level": null,
        "status": "1",
        "created_at": "2022-01-01T18:43:51.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-15T22:52:54.000000Z",
        "subcategories": []
    }, {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Office & Stationery",
        "slug": "office--stationery",
        "image": "public\/uploads\/category\/1642326827-office-stationary.png",
        "frontProduct": null,
        "level": null,
        "status": "1",
        "created_at": "2022-01-15T22:53:47.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-15T22:53:47.000000Z",
        "subcategories": []
    }, {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Pet Care",
        "slug": "pet-care",
        "image": "public\/uploads\/category\/1642326888-pet-care.png",
        "frontProduct": "1",
        "level": null,
        "status": "1",
        "created_at": "2022-01-15T22:54:48.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-15T22:54:48.000000Z",
        "subcategories": [{
            "id": 9,
            "subcategoryName": "Kitten Food",
            "slug": "kitten-food",
            "image": "public\/uploads\/subcategory\/1642334752-kitten-food.jpg",
            "banner": "public\/uploads\/subcategory\/1642334752-kitten-food-banner.jpg",
            "category_id": "8",
            "status": "1",
            "created_at": "2022-01-16T01:05:52.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-01-16T01:05:52.000000Z",
            "childcategories": []
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Toys & Games",
        "slug": "toys--games",
        "image": "public\/uploads\/category\/1642327094-toy-and-games.jpg",
        "frontProduct": "1",
        "level": null,
        "status": "1",
        "created_at": "2022-01-15T22:58:14.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-15T22:58:14.000000Z",
        "subcategories": []
    }, {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Home & Cleaning",
        "slug": "home--cleaning",
        "image": "public\/uploads\/category\/1642327182-house-cleaning.jpg",
        "frontProduct": null,
        "level": null,
        "status": "1",
        "created_at": "2022-01-15T22:59:42.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-15T22:59:42.000000Z",
        "subcategories": []
    }, {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Sports & Fitness",
        "slug": "sports--fitness",
        "image": "public\/uploads\/category\/1642327903-sports-and-fitness.jpg",
        "frontProduct": null,
        "level": null,
        "status": "1",
        "created_at": "2022-01-15T23:11:43.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-15T23:11:43.000000Z",
        "subcategories": []
    }, {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Kitchen & Home Appliances",
        "slug": "kitchen--home-appliances",
        "image": "public\/uploads\/category\/1642327984-home-and-kitchen.png",
        "frontProduct": null,
        "level": null,
        "status": "1",
        "created_at": "2022-01-15T23:13:04.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-15T23:13:04.000000Z",
        "subcategories": []
    }]
}
```

**Here Is My all Code -**

`CategoryModel.dart` file

```
import 'package:Darucheeni/src/models/subCategoryModel.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
part 'categoryModel.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class CategoryModel {
  final int? id;
  final String? name;
  final String? slug;
  final String? image;
  final SubCategoryModel? subCategoryModel;

  CategoryModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.slug,
    required this.image,
    required this.subCategoryModel,
  });

  factory CategoryModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CategoryModelFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CategoryModelToJson(this);
}
```

**Here Is CategoryModel.g.dart**

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'categoryModel.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

CategoryModel _$CategoryModelFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
    CategoryModel(
      id: json['id'] as int?,
      name: json['name'] as String?,
      slug: json['slug'] as String?,
      image: json['image'] as String?,
      subCategoryModel: json['subCategoryModel'] == null
          ? null
          : SubCategoryModel.fromJson(
              json['subCategoryModel'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$CategoryModelToJson(CategoryModel instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      'id': instance.id,
      'name': instance.name,
      'slug': instance.slug,
      'image': instance.image,
      'subCategoryModel': instance.subCategoryModel,
    };
```

Here Is my `categoryController.dart` file

```
import 'package:Darucheeni/src/configs/appConfigs.dart';
import 'package:Darucheeni/src/models/categoryModel.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class CategoryController extends GetxController {
  final dio = Dio();

  final allCategoryList = RxList<CategoryModel>();

  getAllCategory() async {
    try {
      final res = await dio.get(baseUrl + 'all-category');

      final List<CategoryModel> categoryData = res.data['categories']
          .map((json) => CategoryModel.fromJson(json))
          .toList()
          .cast<CategoryModel>();

      print('------------------------------>');
      print('Status Code : ${res.statusCode}');
      print('Headers : ${res.headers}');
      print('realUri : ${res.realUri}');
      print('statusMessage : ${res.statusMessage}');
      print(res.data);
      print('Category Data : $categoryData');
      print('requestOptions : ${res.requestOptions}');
      // print(res.body);
      // print(res.unauthorized);
      print('------------------------------>');

      if (res.data == 200) {
        allCategoryList.addAll(
            (res.data as List).map((e) => CategoryModel.fromJson(e)).toList());
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print a class, you should override 'toString' method. Console is don't know how to print classes

```dart
import 'package:Darucheeni/src/models/subCategoryModel.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
part 'categoryModel.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class CategoryModel {
  final int? id;
  final String? name;
  final String? slug;
  final String? image;
  final SubCategoryModel? subCategoryModel;

  CategoryModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.slug,
    required this.image,
    required this.subCategoryModel,
  });

  factory CategoryModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CategoryModelFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CategoryModelToJson(this);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'CategoryModel{ id: $id, name: $name, slug: $slug, image: $image, SubCategoryModel: $subCategoryModel}';
  }

}
```

Comment: Bro , All is working perfect. But I don't know why the subCategory and Child Category show me to Null. https://ibb.co/6thJL17

Comment: Your problem is calling the wrong key. You are calling the 'subCategoryModel' key, but you must call the 'subcategories' key. Based on the JSON example you added.

Comment: solved bro.....

Comment: if this answer is right for your question, you should click the approval icon button on my answer. and you are welcome

Comment: ok.....................................